# Scraping the "Compare Vintages" from Vivino

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from Vivino, and so far I managed to use the API and read from the json file using this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224619/7575172

```py
r = requests.get(
    "https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore",
    params = {
        "country_code": "DK",
        "country_codes[]":"fr",
        "currency_code":"DKK",
        "grape_filter":"varietal",
        "min_rating":"1",
        "order_by":"price",
        "order":"asc",
        "page": 1,
        "price_range_max":"500",
        "price_range_min":"0",
        "wine_type_ids[]":"1",
        
    },
    headers= {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
    }
)
results = [
    (
        t["vintage"]["wine"]["winery"]["name"], 
        f'{t["vintage"]["wine"]["name"]}',
        t['vintage']['year'],
        t['vintage']['wine']['region']['country']['name'],
        # t['vintage']['wine']['region']['name_en'],
        t['vintage']['wine']['style']['region']['name'],
        t["vintage"]["statistics"]["ratings_average"],
        t["vintage"]["statistics"]["ratings_count"],
        t['price']['amount']
    )
    for t in r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"]
]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(results,columns=
                         ['Winery',
                          'Wine',
                          'Year',
                          'Country',
                          'Region',
                          'Rating',
                          'num_review',
                          'Price'])

# print(dataframe)
print(dataframe[['Winery','Year','Region','Rating','num_review','Price']])
```

However, I cannot find the data that describes the other available vintages of the same wine in any of the json files. E.g. I'm looking at 2019, but data is also available for 2015-2020.

**I have used the network monitor in Firefox to inspect other json files that are sent when you open the page below**. But as far as I can see, the information about total available vintages is not present?

An example of the section I want to scrape can be seen here and in the image:
https://www.vivino.com/DK/en/pierre-amadieu-gigondas-romane-machotte-rouge/w/73846?ref=nav-search#vintageListSection

[image]

Comment: Please update with your version of the code as it pertains to the image above, add a language tag e.g. python, and show some rows of expected output. Ideally, at least one that is retrieved and one that is missing and desired.

Comment: Plus link: https://www.vivino.com/DK/en/pierre-amadieu-gigondas-romane-machotte-rouge/w/73846?ref=nav-search#vintageListSection

Comment: @QHarr I have updated with the code and a link.

Comment: The link is for a different wine. Aren't you trying to compare vintages for machotte-rouge? I don't feel comfortable trawling their databases for all of their data.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, I have updated the link now. Please notice however that the exact wine is not important, but rather I'm interested in a general method to identify what other vintages are available for a given wine (when I have the wine ID), if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is located in the javascript under `window.__PRELOADED_STATE__.winePageInformation` object like this:

```html
<script>
  window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ....
  window.__PRELOADED_STATE__.winePageInformation = { very long JSON here }
</script>
```

You can use a regex to extract it, and the result seems to be valid JSON:

```py
import requests
import re
import json

url = "https://www.vivino.com/DK/en/pierre-amadieu-gigondas-romane-machotte-rouge/w/73846"
r = requests.get(url,
headers= {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
})
# this gets the javascript object
res = re.search(r"^.*window\.__PRELOADED_STATE__\.winePageInformation\s*=\s*(.*});", r.text, re.MULTILINE)
print( r.text)
data = json.loads(res.group(1))

print("recommended vintages")
print(data["recommended_vintages"])

print("all vintages")
print(data["wine"]["vintages"])
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Just out of curiosity, do you know why this is not visible as a json file from a GET request to the API just like the other data? It seems odd to me.

Comment: @MalteJensen I guess the data is cached server side

Comment: One thing though, this gives me problems if there's any semicolon inside the json file, so I made a hacky solution to make it work (I'm not great with regex). See e.g. this: https://www.vivino.com/DK/en/vidal-fleury-ventoux/w/1157565

Comment: @MalteJensen I've updated the regex like this `(.*});`

Answer (score 1):

Bertrand has given you the best answer. Perhaps oddly, the endpoint you are hitting is not configured for allowing you to pass in a wine id and get all vintages back. The available params are:

```
country_code, country_codes, currency_code, discount_prices, food_ids, 
grape_ids, grape_filter, max_rating, merchant_id, merchant_type, min_rating,
min_ratings_count, order_by, order, page, per_page, price_range_max, 
price_range_min, region_ids, wine_style_ids, wine_type_ids, winery_ids, 
vintage_ids, wine_years, excluding_vintage_id, wsa_year, top_list_filter
```

These are detailed in the JS file `https://www.vivino.com/packs/common-8f26f13b0ac53f391471.js`.

You would need to determine the vintage ids and pass those in to the API instead.